# mean_y = np.mean(Y) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

When executing this code

```py
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(20.0,10.0)

#Reading data
data=pd.read_csv("/home/root123/bat_fig.csv",encoding='latin1')
print(data.shape)
data.head()

#collecting data x and y
X=data['Mat'].values
Y=data['100'].values

#Mean X and Y
mean_x = np.mean(X)
mean_y = np.mean(Y)

#Total number of values
n = len(X)

#Using the formula 
numer +=(X[i]-mean_x)*(Y[i]-mean_y)
denom +=(X[i]-mean_x)**2
b1=numer/denom
bo=mean_y-(b1*mean_x)

#print coefficient
print(b1,b0)
```

I get a TypeError on `mean_y = np.mean(Y)`:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: What is `Y`?  Sample values?

Comment: I had taken from csv files they are in integer form

Comment: Don't assume.  Check.